# Re-releasing an iOS app in other countries?

Tags: ios, app-store, auto-update

I have an app that I pulled from countries outside of the US due to a major bug regarding reverse geocoding. I have fixed that bug and resubmitted for review by Apple, but I'm curious if users in other countries that already purchased the app will get the update automatically when it is released by Apple?

I'm assuming that I would need to make the current (buggy) version available in those countries that I want to get the update in before the new version is released at the very least?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the App Store, and is [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that enabling the version for other countries will enable them to download whatever the current version of your app is at the time. So, if you enabled them (say) the day before your update was released then people in those countries would get the current (buggy) version first, and would be updated when the new version was released.

It would seem better to enable the other countries just after your update was released, to avoid negative reviews.